# Multiple Routers in a Backbone (maybe Marionette) app

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I currently have defined multple routers for my Backbone app (non-**[Marionette](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette)** yet).

```
authRouter = new AuthRouter()
usersRouter = new UsersRouter()
...

# then to use them
authRouter.navigate "auth/login"
usersRouter.navigate "users/changePassword"
```

As you can see I am using the variables to navigate. So I must know which router to call. Is it possible to somehow organize code into separate classes but when I want to navigate, just call `appRouter.navigate "something"` instead of needing to know which router is it? Marionette recommends not having big routers but doesn't have a recommended way/example of it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the annotated source code for Backbone, you'll notice that calling `myRouter.navigate` is nothing more than a forwarding method call to `Backbone.history.navigate`

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-114

So there's no need to keep track of routers for the navigate method. You can call Backbone.history.navigate directly.

`Backbone.history.navigate "auth/login"`